# Change theme's thumbnail to cropped WP featured image

Tags: themes, post-thumbnails

The theme I'm using, when browsing a particular category, displays the full featured image (even if it's more than 1000px high), resized to `max-width:20%`. However, I'd like it to display just a cropped thumbnail that was autogenerated by Wordpress. Here's the relevant code:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
    $full_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( get_the_ID() ), 'original') ;

    echo '<article class="search-entry clearfix">';

    if ( $thumb ) {
        $image = hb_resize( $thumb, '', 215, 140, true );
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'" class="search-portfolio-thumb"><img src="'.$image['url'].'" /></a>';
    }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Pass a different size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

```
$image_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail');
```

Here's a more specific example:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    echo '<article class="search-entry clearfix">';

    $image_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail');

    echo ( $image_thumb ) ? sprintf('<a href="%s" title="%s" class="search-portfolio-thumb">%s</a>', get_permalink(), get_the_title(), $image_thumb) : '';
```

Comment: Forgive me for the ignorance, but is this line supposed to replace the one above beginning with `$image = hb_resize` and then use `$image_thumb` instead of `$image` in the following line?

Comment: I added a more specific example that would replace what you had originally posted.

Comment: No Problemo. Glad I could help.